# How to compile with -mno-cygwin or without including cygwin dll's with gcc 4?

Tags: windows, gcc, dll, java-native-interface, cygwin

I'm trying to build the example code for JNI, Java Native Interface, as shown by the tutorial here: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html. The problem arises when I attempt to compile. With gcc-3 in Cygwin it was possible to use the -mno-cygwin flag to compile a stand-alone dll that did not rely on Cygwin's dlls. However, that has been depreciated in gcc-4 which is the compile that I have.

So when I add the flag to my Makefile:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-cygwin’
```

And when I take it out, the project compiles but returns this error when attempting to run the program:

```
$ java HelloJNI
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180103bd9, pid=8604, tid=11116
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b15) (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [cygwin1.dll+0xc3bd9]
```

This output just tells me that it can't find the cygwin dll's. Is there a way with Cygwin and gcc-4 to compile without dependency on the Cygwin dlls? I'm thinking I might revert back to gcc-3 if there's no solution here.

Comment: Use the i686-pc-mingw32-gcc executable provided with cygwin to do the compile.